# Qt Creator building with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator

I would like to build a 64 bit app with Qt Creator on Windows so unfortunately I have to use MSVC compiler. 
I had installed Qt Creator with required SDK but still I couldn't build with MSVC2013 toolchain since I didn't have the compiler.

Event though I had MSVC 2015 installed with Visual Studio 2015, that wasn't enough for Qt Creator. I didn't feel like installing Visual Studio 2013, so I copied only the MSVC 2013 compiler from my friends Visual Studio 2013 directory. Still it wasn't listed in Qt's autodetected compilers. I found the config xml  under:

> C:\Users\usr\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\toolchains.xml

and added path for MSVC2013, copying autodetected paths for MSVC2015 and editing one number.

Now my MSVC2013 toolchain is working... in theory because compiling with it results in an error:

> C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore\qglobal.h:39: błąd: C1083: Cannot
>   open include file: 'cstddef': No such file or directory

It doesn't include standard library files. How to fix it? How to cofigure Qt to work with MSCV2013 64 bit?

Comment: "I didn't feel like installing Visual Studio 2013, so I copied only the MSVC 2013 compiler from my friends Visual Studio 2013 directory. ". That's a bad idea. In general it won't work - there are a lot of registry values written during installation. Plus each version comes with its own stl implementation. So just install VS2013 - you will save time

Comment: You cannot mix a compiler with a CRT that didn't ship with that compiler. They are - in general - incompatible. If you want to use the Microsoft Compiler that ships with Visual Studio 2013, you have to install Visual Studio 2013.