# MSVC2017 is not recognized by QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, msvc14

I installed VS 2017, and then installed Qt Creator 4.5.2 with the MSVC2017 plug-in.

I reboot the necessary times...

I launch QtCreator, the Qt kit for MSVC2017 is there but the compiler is not.

I add cl.exe manually, but it fails to compile as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569139/qtcreator-qmake-cannot-run-compiler-cl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).
I reinstalled Qt as suggested, but the problems persist.

**How do I set MSVC2017 up to work properly with QtCreator?**

PS: Other stack overflow questions did not hep either ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229225/using-qt-creator-5-8-with-msvc-2015-compiler?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171416/qt-creator-building-with-msvc?rq=1))

Answer (score 0):

Please verify if you have installed msvc2017 32 / 64 bit and the same version and Qt libraries.
If yes please check to have installed the Visual Studio build tools.

Comment: How can I check if I have Visual Studio build tools? I have the full VS2017 and I can compile c++ with it.